# Use of LaTeX (MathJax) in E.L.U

Tags: support

I have noticed that it not not possible to use MathJax (LaTeX) in E.L.U., while this is indeed possible in other sites of StackExchange.

Is there any particular reason why the use LaTeX (MathJax) is not possible E.L.U.?

Comment: Simply because barely anyone here ever needs it. In fact, this is probably the first request of this kind. Can you elaborate on what kind of situations you'd want to use it in? Most SE sites do not support it. There are only five or six, out of 100+ and counting, that do. (Also, on a personal note, MathJax makes the loading times for me unbearable, which is why I don't visit Mathematics or CSTheory anywhere as often as I'd like to, and why I curse and swear every time I click on them by accident.)

Comment: Apparently, I am interested in using certain symbols, and MathJax offers this capability.

Comment: Yes, but that is still not very clear. If you plan on using individual symbols, Unicode has a code point for everything. And if you need to format a complicated equation, that's simply too rare an occurrence on this site to force-feed MathJax to all users at all times, so you can just render it elsewhere and post an image of it.

Comment: Which symbols do you want?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want are special symbols, then Unicode v6.1 has 940 code points with the ***General Category*** of **Math Symbol** and 2,195 code points with the ***General Category*** of **Other Symbol**. (I haven’t tallied more recent releases, let alone the impending Unicode v7.0 release.)

I’ve a hunch you might find what you are looking for amongst those.

Or rather, amongst these:

```
⦟ ≌ ≊ ≈ ⩯ ⨿ ⟑ ∠ ⦞ ⦤ ⥀ ∳ ⟲ ⨑ ≐ ≆ ⩰ ≅ ≒    ⤶ ⤷ ⤵ ⤴ ⊦ ∗ ≃ ∵ ≬ ⧹ ⧸ ⧓ ⧭
⧪ ⧗ ⧫ ◾ ◼ ⤻  ⌡   ⋈ ⧑ ⧒ ∙ ⦼ ⊛ ⦿ ⊝ ⨸ ⊘ ⊙ ⊜ ⧁ ⦺ ⧀ ⊖ ⨶ ⦷ ⦹ ⊕ ⦸ ⊚ ⊗ ⦶ ⦾
⦵ ⧂ ⦻ ⧃ ⨐ ⥁ ∲ ⟳ ∱ ⩍ ⫏ ⫑ ⫐ ⫒ ⩌ ⩐ ≔ ⁒ ∁ ⩭ ∋ ⊳ ⊵ ⋺ ⋽ ⋻ ∮ ≘ ∛ ⎪ ⋏ ⋎ ≜
⋄ ≏ ∣ ÷ ∕ ⋇ ∌ ⋫ ⋭ ∤ ⫮ ⊮ ⊀ ⋠ ⊬ ⊁ ⋡ ∸ ⋅ ∔ ⦙ ⩴ ⫪ ⧟ ∬ ⋒ ⪚ ⪙ ⪜ ⪛ ⫺ ⫹ ⩓
⩔ ⪢ ⪡ ⪣ ⧺ ⪻ ⫽ ⩎ ⩏ ⫬ ⅀ ⋐ ⪼ ⋑ ⋓ ⫫ ⫥ ⊫ ⫣ ⥿ ⧨ ⧩ ⋱ ⊤ ⫱ ↓ ⇵ ⤓ ⤈ ⥥ ⥯ ⥡ ⥙
⥝ ⥕ ⟱ ⤋ ∈ ⫙ ⟒ ⋵ ⋲ ⋶ ⋹ ⋸ ⋳ ∅ ⦴ ⦱ ⦳ ⦲ ∎ ⋕ ≕ =  ⩱ ⥱ ⩳ ⧣ ⧤ ⪮ ⩦ ⩷ ⩮ ≝ ⋝
⋜ ⋞ ⋟ ≚ ≍ ⩸ ⧳ ⧱ ⧯ ⧲ ⧰ ⧮ ≙ ∹ ⤯ ⤬ ⨍ ∀ ⊩ ⫝̸ ∜ ⁄ ⟗ ＝ ＞ ＜ ￢ ＋ ～ ｜
≑ ≎ ∺ ⧦ ⪌ ⪒ ⥸ ⪐ ⪎ ⪔ ⪊ ⪈ ⪥ ≩ ⋧ ⪧ ⪩ ⋛ ⪆ ≥ ≳ ≷ ⩾ ⪂ ⪄ ⪀ ≧ ⪤ > ⩺ ⋗ ⩼ ϶
￬ ￩ ￫ ￪ ﬩ ⊹ ∻ ⎯ ≡ ⧥ ⩧ ⊷ ≓ ⧜ ⧡ ∆ ∞ ⧞ ∫ ⨕ ⨏ ⎮ ⨎ ⨙ ⨗ ⨛ ⨘ ⨜ ⨚ ⊺ ⨼ ∩ ⩉
⩇ ⩋ ⩀ ⩄ ⩃ ∾ ⨝ ⟙ ⨞ ⪫ ⪭ ⫼ ⟘ ⟚ ⟛   ⥐ ⥋ ⥊ ⥎ ⌈ ⎩ ⎨ ⎧ ⥼ ⌊ ⟜ ⋉ ⟕ ⎜ ⎝ ⎛ ↔
⥈ ⇼ ↮ ⇹ ⇔ ⇎ ⤄ ⇿ ⋋ ⤹ ⎢ ⎣ ⎡ ⊣ ⧏ ←    ⥃ ⥳ ⤟ ⤙ ⥷ ⥺  ⤝  ⇺ ⥆ ↚   ⇷ ⤆ ⤛ ⤂
⤌ ⥧ ⥫ ⥞ ⥖ ⥢ ⥪ ⥦ ⥚ ⥒ ⇽ ⤎        ⪋ ⪑ ⥶ ⪏ ⪍ ⪓ ⪉ ⪇ ≨ ⋦ ⪦ ⪨ ⋚ ⪅ ≤ ≲ ≶ ⩽
⪁ ⪃ ⩿ ≦ < ⩹ ⋖ ⩻ ⨔ ⨒ ⨓ ∧ ⩑ ⩞ ⩠ ⩜ ⩚ ⩟ ∨ ⩙ ⩒ ⩢ ⩣ ⩝ ⩛ ⫦  ⟷ ⟺ ⟞ ⟵ ⟻ ⟸ ⟽
⟝ ⟶ ⟼ ⟹ ⟾ ⟿ ⤿ ◺ ⟓ ⤾ ◿ ⟠   ∡ ⦛ ⦫ ⦪ ⦯ ⦭ ⦮ ⦬ ⦩ ⦨ ≞ ⦝ ⋯ ∓ − ⨺ ⨩ ⨪ ⨫ ⨬
≂ ⧿ ⊧ ⨊ ≫ ≪ ⊸ × ⨷ ⨴ ⨵ ⨻ ⨰ ⨱ ⊌ ⊍ ⊎ ♯ ∇ ⊼ ⨀ ⨁ ⨂ ∐ ⋂ ⋀ ⋁ ∏ ⨅ ⨆ ∑ ⨉ ⋃
⨃ ⨄ ⫿ ⊯ ≇ ⊈ ⊉ ≱ ≵ ≹ ≰ ≴ ≸ ⫝ ⊽ ⊲ ⊴ ⤢ ⤨ ⤱ ⤮ ⤤ ⤡ ⤧ ⤲ ⤣ ≉ ∉ ⊄ ⊅ ≄ ≠ ≭
≯ ≢ ≮ ⋪ ⋬ ∦ ¬ ⋢ ⋣ ≁ ⊭ ⦧ ⦦   ⊶  ∥ ⫲ ⫳ ∂  ⫡ ⋔ ⫚ ± + ⩲ ⨭ ⨮ ⨹ ⨨ ⨣ ⨥ ⨢
⨧ ⨤ ⨦ ≺ ⪷ ⪳ ⪹ ⪵ ⪯ ⪱ ⋨ ≼ ≾ ⊰ ∷ ∝ ⨌ ⨖ ≟ ∶ ⦣ ⦥ ⫭ ⦰ ⅃ ∽ ⋍ ⧵  ⧷   ∟ ⦜ ⊾
⍼ ⟴ ⇴ ⌉ ⎭ ⎬ ⎫ ⥰ ⥽ ⌋ ⨽ ⋊ ⟖ ⎟ ⎠ ⎞ ⋌ ⤸ ⎥ ⎦ ⎤ ⊢ ⊿ ⧎ → ⥵   ⥂ ⥴ ↦ ⤠ ⤚   ⥇
⤞ ⤑ ⇻ ⥅ ↛ ↣ ⤕ ⤔ ⇸ ⇒ ⤇ ⤜ ⇏ ⤃ ⤍ ⥩ ⥭ ⥟ ⥗ ⥨ ⥬ ⥤ ⥛ ⥓ ⇾ ⤏ ↠ ⤅ ⤁ ⤖ ⤘ ⤗ ⤀
⤐ ≗ ≖ ∘ ⤫ ⤰ ⧴ ⨲ ∖ ⫟ ⫧ ⫞ ⥄ ⫠ ⫩ ⫨ ⧢ ⪠ ⪟ ⩬ ⪞ ⪝ ∿ ⧌ ⪖ ⪘ ⪕ ⪗ ⩘ ⩗ ∍ ⋾ ⋼
∊ ⋷ ⋴ ﹦ ⪪ ⪬ ﹥ ﹤ ﹢ ⩡ ⨳ ⧶ ⤩ ⤭ ⤥ ⤪ ⤦ ∢ ⦠ ⦡ ⊓ ⊔ ⧆ ⊡ ⧅   ⊟ ⊞ ⧄ ⧇ ⧈
⊠ ⊏ ⊑ ⋤ ⫍ ⊐ ⊒ ⋥ ⫎ √ ⧠ ≛ ⋆ ≣ ₌ ₋ ₊ ⥹ ⫕ ⫓ ⊂ ⫉ ⫅ ⫋ ⫇ ⊆ ⫃ ⊊ ⪽ ⫁ ⪿ ≻ ⪸
⪴ ⪺ ⪶ ⪰ ⪲ ⋩ ≽ ≿ ⊱ ⎳ ⎲ ⨋ ⁼ ⁻ ⁺ ⥻ ⫔ ⫖ ⫘ ⫗ ⊃ ⫊ ⫆ ⫌ ⫈ ⊇ ⫄ ⊋  ⪾ ⫂ ⫀ ∯ ∄
∃ ∴ ⧧ ⩶   ⇶ ⧝ ~ ∼  ⥲ ⩪ ⩫ ⧔ ⧕ ⧾ ⤺ ⤽ ⤼  ⌠   ⫛ ⧊ ⧍ ⧋ ⫶ ⩨ ⩩ ∭ ⫸ ⫷ ⧻ ⫻
≋ ⫴ ⦀ ⊪ ⫵ ⊨ ⅋ ⦢ ⅁ ⅂ ⅄ ⩵ ⩕ ⩖ ⧉ ⨇ ⨈ ∪ ⩈ ⩆ ⩊ ⩅ ⩁ ⩂ ⦽ ⥑ ⥍ ⥌ ⥏ ⥾ ⟔ ⎰ ◸
⎱ ◹ ⋰ ⊥ ⟟ ↑ ⤒ ⤉ ⥮ ⥣ ⥠ ⥘ ⥜ ⥔ ⟰ ⤊ ⥉ ⨯ ⧐ ⫤ ⫢  ⋮ | ⫯ ⫰ ⦚ ⋙ ⋘ ∰  ⤳ ℘ ⧬
⟡ ⟢ ⟣ ⟐ ⧖ ◁ ◽ ◻ ▷ ⟤ ⟥  ⫾ ≀ ⊻ ⋿ ⩤ ⩥ ⨾ ⨟ ⨠ ⨡ ⦁ ⦂
```

If what you are looking for is the “math letters” from the **Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols *Block***, those are these:

If you tally together all the characters with the **Math** property, I get the following 2,310 of them, sorted:

```
                                        
          ⦟ ≌ ≊ ≈ ⩯ ⨿                         
  ⟑ ∠ ⦞ ⦤ ⥀ ∳ ⟲ ⨑ ↶ ≐ ≆ ⩰ ≅ ≒ ؆ ؇   ؈ ⤶ ⤷ ⤵ ⤴ ⊦ ∗ ≃ ∵ ≬ ⧹ ⧸ ⧓ ● ⧭ ♣ ◆ ⧪ ▾ ▼ 
⧗ ◀ ◢ ⧫ ◾ ◼ ▰ ▶ ♠ ■ ★ ◤ ▴ ▲ ▮                          
⤻ ⏟ ⌡ ⏝ ⎵ ⏡ ⋈ ⧑ ⧒ ℬ ∙ ℭ ℂ ⁀ ⦼ ⊛ ⦿ ⊝ ⨸ ⊘ ⊙ ⊜ ⧁ ⦺ ⧀ ⊖ ⨶ ⦷ ⦹ ⊕ ⦸ ⊚ ⊗ ⦶ ⦾ ⦵ ◐ ◒ ◑ ⧂ 
⦻ ⧃ ◓ ⨐ ^ ⥁ ∲ ⟳ ∱ ↷ ⩍ ⫏ ⫑ ⫐ ⫒ ⩌ ⩐                        
 ≔ ○⃔ ○⃚ ○⃕ ○⃙ ○⃦ ○⃜ ○⃖ ○⃮ ○⃐ ○⃡ ○⃭ ○⃫ ○⃒ ○⃥ ○⃗ ○⃯ ○⃑ ○⃬ ○⃘ ○⃓ ○⃛ ⁒ ∁ ⩭ ∋ ⊳ ⊵ ⋺ ⋽ ⋻ ∮ ≘ ∛ ⎪ ⋏ ⋎ ⅅ ⅆ 
≜ ⋄ ≏ ∣ ÷ ∕ ⋇                           ∌ ⋫ ⋭ ∤ ⫮ ⊮ ⊀ 
⋠ ⊬ ⊁ ⋡ ∸ ⋅ ∔ ⦙ ⩴ ⫪ ⧟ ∬ ⋒ ⦕ ⪚ ⪙ ⪜ ⪛ ⫺ ⫹ ⩓ ⩔ ⪢ ⪡ ⪣ ⧺ ⪻ ″ ⦖ ⫽ ⩎ ⩏ ⫬ ⅀ ⋐ ⪼ ⋑ ⋓ ⫫ ⫥ 
⊫ ⫣ ‖ ⥿ ⧨ ⧩ ⋱ ⊤ ⫱ ↓ ↧ ⇵ ⤓ ⤈ ⇓ ⥥ ⥯ ⥡ ⥙ ⇃ ⥝ ⥕ ⇂ ⇊ ⟱ ⤋ ↡ ⅇ ∈ ⫙ ⟒ ⋵ ⋲ ⋶ ⋹ ⋸ ⋳    
                     ∅ ⦴ ⦱ ⦳ ⦲ ∎ ⋕ ≕ = ⭀ ⩱ ⥱ ⩳ ⧣ ⧤ ⪮ ⩦ ⩷ ⩮ 
≝ ⋝ ⋜ ⋞ ⋟ ≚ ≍ ⩸ ⧳ ⧱ ⧯ ⧲ ⧰ ⧮ ℰ ℯ ≙ ∹ ℇ ⤯ ⤬ ♀ ⨍                  
        ∀ ⊩ ⫝̸ ∜ ⁄ ℱ ⟗ ＾ ＝ ＞ ＜ ￢ ＋ ＼ ～ ｜ ⁡ ≑ ≎ ∺ ⧦        
                  ⪌ ⪒ ⥸ ⪐ ⪎ ⪔ ⪊ ⪈ ⪥ ≩ ⋧ ⪧ ⪩ ⋛ ⪆ ≥ ≳ ≷ ⩾ ⪂ ⪄ ⪀ 
≧ ⪤ > ⩺ ⋗ ⩼ ϶ ℊ ￬ ￩ ￫ ￪ ℌ ℍ ﬩ ⊹                       ∻ ⎯ 
ℎ ℏ ℋ ℑ ≡ ⧥ ⩧ ⅈ ⊷ ≓                         ⧜ ⧡ ∆ ∞ ⧞ ∫ 
⨕ ⨏ ⎮ ⨎ ⨙ ⨗ ⨛ ⨘ ⨜ ⨚ ⊺ ⨼ ∩ ⩉ ⩇ ⩋ ⩀ ⩄ ⩃ ∾ ⁤ ⁣ ⁢ ℐ  ⅉ                 
          ⨝                            ⟙ ⨞ 
⪫ ⪭ ⫼ ⟘ ⟚ ⟛ ⦑ ⦓ ⬲ ⬰ ⥐ ⥋ ⥊ ⥎ ⦗ ⌈ ⎩ ⎨ ⎧ ⧚ ⥼ ⌊ ⟜ ⋉ ⟕ ⎜ ⎝ ⎛ ⧼ ↔ ⥈ ⇼ ↮ ⇹ ⇔ ⇎ ⤄ ⇿ ↭ ⋋ 
⤹ ⎢ ⎣ ⎡ ⦏ ⦍ ⦋ ⟅ ⊣ ⧏ ← ⭊ ⭂ ⭋ ⥃ ⥳ ↤ ⤟ ⇆ ⤙ ⥷ ⥺ ⬾ ⇤ ⤝ ⬸ ⇺ ↩ ↫ ⥆ ↚ ↢ ⬺ ⬹ ⇷ ⇐ ⤆ ⤛ ⇍ ⤂ 
⤌ ⇋ ⥧ ⥫ ⥞ ⥖ ↽ ⥢ ⥪ ⥦ ⥚ ⥒ ↼ ⇽ ⇇ ⇚ ⤎ ↞ ⬶ ⬵ ⬻ ⬽ ⬼ ⬴ ⬷ ↜ ⦃ ⦅ ⧘ ⪋ ⪑ ⥶ ⪏ ⪍ ⪓ ⪉ ⪇ ≨ ⋦ ⪦ 
⪨ ⋚ ⪅ ≤ ≲ ≶ ⩽ ⪁ ⪃ ⩿ ≦ < ⩹ ⋖ ⩻ ⨔ ⨒ ⨓                       
   ∧ ⩑ ⩞ ⩠ ⩜ ⩚ ⩟ ∨ ⩙ ⩒ ⩢ ⩣ ⩝ ⩛ ⫦ ⟌ ⟷ ⟺ ⟞ ⟵ ⟻ ⟸ ⟽ ⬳ ⟝ ⟶ ⟼ ⟹ ⟾ ⟿ ⤿ ◺ ⟓ ⤾ ◿ ◊ ⟠ 
ℒ ℓ ♂     ⟍   ⟨ ⟪ ⟮ ⟦ ⟬ ⟩ ⟫ ⟯ ⟧ ⟭ ⟋     ∡ ⦛ ⦫ ⦪ ⦯ ⦭ ⦮ ⦬ ⦩ ⦨ ≞ ⦝ ⋯ ∓ − 
⨺ ⨩ ⨪ ⨫ ⨬ ≂ ⧿                          ⊧ ⨊ ℳ ≫ ≪ ⊸ × ⨷ 
⨴ ⨵ ⨻ ⨰ ⨱ ⊌ ⊍ ⊎ ♭ ♮ ♯ ∇ ⊼ ⨀ ⨁ ⨂ ∐ ⋂ ⋀ ⋁ ∏ ⨅ ⨆ ∑ ⨉ ⋃ ⨃ ⨄ ⫿ ℕ ⊯ ≇ ⊈ ⊉ ≱ ≵ ≹ ≰ ≴ ≸ 
                         ⫝ ⊽ ⊲ ⊴ ⤢ ↗ ⤨ ⤱ ⤮ ⤤ ⇗ ⤡ ↖ ⤧ ⤲ 
⤣ ⇖ ≉ ∉ ⊄ ⊅ ≄ ≠ ≭ ≯ ≢ ≮ ⋪ ⋬ ∦ ¬ ⋢ ⋣ ≁ ⊭ ⦧ ⦦                   
       ⟃ ⟄ ⊶ ⟇ ℴ ∥ ⫲ ⫳ ∂ ℙ ⟂ ⫡ ⋔ ⫚ ± + ⩲ ⨭ ⨮ ⨹ ⨨ ⨣ ⨥ ⨢ ⨧ ⨤ ⨦       
                   ≺ ⪷ ⪳ ⪹ ⪵ ⪯ ⪱ ⋨ ≼ ≾ ⊰ ′ ∷ ∝ ℚ       
                   ⨌ ⨖ ≟ ⎷ ∶ ℜ ℝ ⦣ ⦥ ⫭ ⦰ ⅃ ∽ ⋍ ⧵ ⟈ ⧷ ⭁ ⭇ ∟ ⦒ 
⦜ ⊾ ⍼ ⦔ ⟴ ⇴ ⦘ ⌉ ⎭ ⎬ ⎫ ⥰ ⧛ ⥽ ⌋ ⨽ ⋊ ⟖ ⎟ ⎠ ⎞ ⧽ ⋌ ⤸ ⎥ ⎦ ⎤ ⦎ ⦐ ⦌ ⟆ ⊢ ⊿ ⧎ → ⥵ ⭈ ⭌ ⥂ ⥴ 
↦ ⤠ ⇄ ⤚ ⭃ ⭄ ⥇ ⇥ ⤞ ⤑ ⇻ ↪ ↬ ⥅ ↛ ↣ ⤕ ⤔ ⇸ ⇒ ⤇ ⤜ ⇏ ⤃ ⤍ ⇌ ⥩ ⥭ ⥟ ⥗ ⇁ ⥨ ⥬ ⥤ ⥛ ⥓ ⇀ ⇾ ⇉ ⇝ 
⇛ ⤏ ↠ ⤅ ⤁ ⤖ ⤘ ⤗ ⤀ ⤐ ↝ ⦄ ⦆ ⧙ ≗ ≖ ∘ ⤫ ⤰                      
  ℛ ⧴ ⨲ ∖ ⫟ ⫧ ⫞ ⥄ ⫠ ⫩ ⫨ ⧢ ⪠ ⪟ ⩬ ⪞ ⪝ ∿ ⧌ ⪖ ⪘ ⪕ ⪗ ⩘ ⩗ ﹡ ∍ ⋾ ⋼ ∊ ⋷ ⋴ ﹦ ⪪ ⪬ ﹥ 
﹣ ﹤ ﹢ ﹨ ⩡ ⨳                           ⧶ ↘ ⤩ ⤭ ⤥ ⇘ 
↙ ⤪ ⤦ ⇙ ∢ ⦠ ⦡ ⊓ ⊔ ⧆ ⊡ ⧅ ⟎ ⟏ ⊟ ⊞ ⧄ ⧇ ⧈ ⊠ ⊏ ⊑ ⋤ ⫍ ⊐ ⊒ ⋥ ⫎ √ ⧠ ◧ ◪ ◨ ◩ ≛ ⋆ ≣ ₌ ₍ ₋ 
₊ ₎ ⥹ ⫕ ⫓ ⊂ ⫉ ⫅ ⫋ ⫇ ⊆ ⫃ ⊊ ⪽ ⫁ ⪿ ≻ ⪸ ⪴ ⪺ ⪶ ⪰ ⪲ ⋩ ≽ ≿ ⊱ ⎳ ⎲ ⨋ ⁼ ⁽ ⁻ ⁺ ⁾ ⥻ ⫔ ⫖ ⫘ ⫗ 
⊃ ⫊ ⫆ ⫌ ⫈ ⊇ ⫄ ⊋ ⟉ ⪾ ⫂ ⫀ ∯ ∄ ∃ ∴ ⧧ ⩶ ⟀ ⬱ ⇶ ⧝ ~ ∼ ⭉ ⥲ ⩪ ⩫ ⧔ ⧕ ⧾          
                 ⤺ ⤽ ⤼ ⏞ ⌠ ⏜ ⎴ ⏠ ⫛ ⧊ ⧍ ⧋ ⫶ ⩨ ⩩ ∭ ⫸ ⫷ ⧻ ‴ ⫻ ≋ ⫴ 
⦀ ⊪ ⫵ ⊨ ⅋ ⦢ ℩ ⅁ ⅂ ⅄ ⩵ ⩕ ⩖ ⧉ ⨇ ⨈                         
  ∪ ⩈ ⩆ ⩊ ⩅ ⩁ ⩂ ⦽ ⥑ ⥍ ⥌ ⥏ ↕ ⇕ ⥾ ⟔ ⎰ ◸ ⎱ ◹ ⋰ ⊥ ⟟ ↑ ↥ ⇅ ⤒ ⤉ ↰ ↱ ⇑ ⥮ ⥣ ⥠ ⥘ ↿ ⥜ ⥔ 
↾ ⇈ ⟰ ⤊ ↟ ⥉ ⨯ ⧐ ⫤ ⫢ ⟊ ⋮ | ⏐ ⫯ ⫰ ⦚ ⋙ ⋘                      
     ∰ ⬿ ⤳ ℘ ○ ⧬ ⟡ ⟢ ⟣ ◇ ♢ ⟐ ▿ ▽ ♡ ⧖ ◁ ◽ ◻ ▱ ▷ □ ⟤ ⟥ ◫ ☆ ⏢ ⟁ ▵ △ ◬ ⫾ ▯   
                        ≀                
           ⊻                           ℨ ℤ 
                        ⋿ ⩤ ⦉ ⦇ ⩥ ⨾ ⦊ ⦈ ⨟ ⨠ ⨡ ⦁ ⦂    
       ϐ           ℾ ℽ                     
ϵ                                      ϴ ϑ 
                              ϰ          
                                        
                ℿ ℼ                ϱ       
                                  ϒ      
     ϕ                                   
           ℵ ℶ ℷ ℸ
```

For more complex MathJax style equations, it is more expedient to first draft your equation on any SE site with MathJax support, then cut out a screenshot of just that portion and load that cut-out as an image here.

Comment: Wow, most of those show up as open squares for me.

Comment: @KitFox Perhaps surprisingly, Firefox 26 on Windows 7 does quite well on that score.

Comment: @Andrew Um, that's what I'm running. Oh! Haha. But not when I looked at this answer last, it seems.

Comment: @KitFox Aha! Yes, squares on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX would have been useful when I was writing [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/151276/2175). As it is, I had to format the equations elsewhere, use screen capture to convert the equations to images, and upload the images. This was a very tedious process compared to entering the equations directly.